# Building a specific Runtime image using Platform Builder 5.0

Tags: windows, windows-ce, builder, platform, platform-builder

I am trying to create a run-time image using Platform Builder 5.0, I know how to make run-time images but I need specific modules and files to be inside the run-time image, I am basically trying to clone an original run-time image and I want to add some extra stuff such as drivers for an ethernet card that was incorrectly configured, by using viewbin I was able to obtain the following modules and files, if it is possible can someone tell me exactly what catalog items I should add because at the moment I am using trial and error and it is not working, the modules and files are as follows

Modules
nk.exe,GIISR.dll, `isr16550.dll`, `coredll.dll`, `filesys.exe`, `gwes.exe`, `device.exe`, `devmgr.dll`, `regenum.dll`, `pm.dll`, `fatfsd.dll`, `diskcache.dll`, `fatutil.dll`, `shell.exe`, `shellcelog.dll`, `toolhelp.dll`, `cmd.exe`, `atapi.dll`, `udfs.dll`, `fsdmgr.dll`, `mspart.dll`, `ceddk.dll`, `ppp.dll`, `pppoe.dll`, `export.dll`, `iphlpapi.dll`, `mbridge.dll`, `winsock.dll`, `ws2.dll`, `wsinstl.dll`, `wspm.dll`, `nspm.dll`, `secur32.dll`, `ntlmssp.dll`, `credsvc.dll`, `credprov.dll`, `afd.dll`, `ndis.dll`, `dhcp.dll`, `tcpstk.dll`, `tapi.dll`, `unimodem.dll`, `netbios.dll`, `ping.exe`, `ipconfig.exe`, `ndisconfig.exe`, `route.exe`, `netstat.exe`, `tracert.exe`, `serial.dll`, `mmtimer.dll`, `ole32.dll`, `oleaut32.dll`, `services.exe`, `httpd.dll`, telnetd.dll,PCIbus.dll, `pcc_tipccard.dll`, `pcc_serv.dll`, `pcmcia.dll`, `kbdmouse.dll`, `com16550.dll`, `ssce20.dll`, `ssceca20.dll`, `e100ce.dll` - this is the driver that I am replacing, `micro.dll`

Files
`ceconfig.h`, wince.nls, `initobj.dat`, `boot.hv`, `default.hv`, `user.hv`, `cemgrc.exe`, `cetlkitl.dll`, `cetlstub.dll`, `tcpipc.dll`,
`tlcesrv.dll`, `httpd_default.htm`, `NTLMInit.exe`, `version.exe`, `HECImageInfo.exe-version.exe` and `HECImageInfo.exe` are run from an app on the drive itself.

I have tried adding the above files and modules that were missing by using the `project.bib` files in the Parameter view, but still this does not help. I am using this system on a MSM586SEN board and there is problems with the ethernet not connecting to the computer.

Answer (score 0):

You can't just go and add these modules and files into your own BIB files.  It's unlikely to work, plus it's a bad idea as there's nothing telling the system to generate those files.  Select what you need from the catalog, which will set the proper SYSGEN veriables.  That, in turn, will build the proper pieces and include them into the OS.

If you want to "clone" what was in an image, but don't have the project file for it, then look in the `\windows\ceconfig.h` file of the running OS.  It will list every SYSGEN set during the build process.  You can then manually set them in your new project, or select the proper catalog items to set them (hover on a catalog item and it will tell you the SYSGEN it sets - alternately you might just manually edit your project file with a text editor and add them).

Once you have that, then you can add drivers, debug connectivity issues, etc.

Comment: How will I add the micro.dll,e100ce.dll and the HecImageInfo.exe to the OS?

Comment: Those you would add either to your BIB file directly, or generate a catalog for your component that sets a SYSGEN which will then include them.